# MySQL insert record to one table to another if postid is not exist

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to write query in better way than this if I want to insert `postid` from `posts` table to `star_ratings` table if the `postid` is not exists in `star_ratings` table.

```
INSERT INTO star_ratings(post_id) 
SELECT postid FROM posts 
WHERE type in ('D', 'B') 
AND postid NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM star_ratings) 
ORDER BY postid ASC
```

Comment: Your query looks exactly as it should :)

Comment: Okay cool. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `EXISTS` query *might* perform slightly better than what you have:

```
INSERT INTO star_ratings (post_id)
SELECT p.postid
FROM posts p
WHERE
    p.type IN ('D', 'B') AND
    NOT EXSITS (SELECT 1 FROM star_ratings s WHERE p.post_id = s.post_id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain me what is `1` stands from in `NOT EXSITS (SELECT 1 FROM star_ratings s WHERE p.post_id = s.post_id);`

Comment: I select `1` as an arbitrary value.  Actually, `EXISTS` checks for the existence of a record, and it doesn't matter what you select.  That being said, not selecting the `post_id` might improve performance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using left join too

```
INSERT INTO star_ratings(post_id) 
SELECT postid FROM posts left join star_ratings on posts.postid=star_ratings.post_id 
WHERE type in ('D', 'B') and star_ratings.post_id is null
```

Comment: I would like to know if `JOIN` is better solution over the no joins?